# How to get array with PHP on Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I've been making a Joomla module. I've mostly been successful, but I have one question: how do you get the `image_fulltext` variable to contain the following?

```
{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/sampledata\/parks\/landscape\/800px_cradle_mountain_seen_from_barn_bluff.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"Konsultasi belajar","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

Comment: use `$arr = json_encode($output);` and get image_fulltext by calling `$arr->image_fulltext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality can be found inside the PHP library see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).